# Calculate > ( or <) than certain percentiles on each grid of a RasterBrick

Tags: r, raster, stat, percentile

How can i get a new raster `r90` that has only those values which are greater than 90th percentile of its values in each grid cell.
For example i tried the follwoing but i am not sure if `r90` is giving me the right thin.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=7)
r <- stack(setValues(r1, runif(ncell(r1))),
           setValues(r1, runif(70 ,0.6,0.9)),
           setValues(r1, runif(70 ,0.2,0.4)),
           setValues(r1, runif(70 ,1,2)))
r

#calcaulte 90th percentile of each grid cells

q90fun <- function(x){quantile(x, probs = .90, na.rm=TRUE)}
q90<-calc(r,fun=q90fun)

#sort raster r with values greater than or equal to its 90th percentile

fun90gt <- function(x,y){x[x >= y]}
r90<-overlay(r,q90,fun=fun90gt)
r90
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works with the example data, but that it may not be OK in general because it is not guaranteed that `fun90gt` will always return the same number of values (consider ties, NA)

Instead of `r90 <- overlay(r, q90, fun=fun90gt)` you could do

```
r90 <- overlay(r, q90, fun=function(x,y) { x[x <= y] <- NA; x })
```

or the equivalent

```
rr <- r > q90
r90 <- mask(r, rr, maskvalue=0)
```

and then perhaps

```
# r90n <- sum(rr)
r90n <- calc(r90, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) )
r90mx <- max(r90, na.rm=TRUE)
r90mn <- min(r90, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, and point to consider. I have a followup, In this case, if each layers represent daily values than how to calculate r90 for each years ie not for all the stacks bot for 365/366 layers.